# Why is this c++ output different than what I expected?

Tags: c++

How is this 54345 and not 54321?
I thought if N is 5 - I which is 3 its 2 minus 1 should be one I dont get how it can increase at all?

```
const int N = 5;
typedef int AList[N];

int main()
{
   AList A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

   for (int I = 0; I < 5; I++) {
      A[I] = A[N-I-1];
   }

   for (int I = 0; I < 5; I++) {
      cout << A[I];
   }
 }
```

Comment: This is a logic problem, not a programming one.

Comment: I dont actually write code like this sorry for the indentation, my wifi is down so I typed it on my phone : /.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm sorry but I'm going to have to edit this into Allman style :p

Comment: @Thomas And then I'm going to have to edit it back again.

Comment: It's fantastic as it is, demonstrating three distinct brace styles if you count "none at all where possible"!

Comment: Gack! C++ isn't FORTRAN! `I` should be `i`! `<g>`

Comment: Boo! Down to two distinct brace styles!

Answer (score 10):

> How is this 54345 and not 54321? I thought if N is 5 - I which is 3 its 2 minus 1 should be one I dont get how it can increase at all?

As that first loop progresses, you're not operating on its original values but on the values that you've already processed in earlier iterations of the loop:

```
for (int I = 0; I < 5; I++) {
   A[I] = A[N-I-1];
}
```

- Iteration 1: set `A[0]` to `A[4]` = `5`
- Iteration 2: set `A[1]` to `A[3]` = `4`
- Iteration 3: set `A[2]` to `A[2]` = `3`
- Iteration 4: set `A[3]` to `A[1]` = `4`
  (used to be `2`, but you changed it in iteration 2!)
- Iteration 5: set `A[4]` to `A[0]` = `5`
  (used to be `1`, but you changed it in iteration 1!)

---

You'd need two arrays — a *source* and a *destination* — to do this properly, or, to be more efficient, `swap` these elements (instead of overwriting them) over a loop that iterates to the midpoint of your input array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N/2; i++) {
   std::swap(A[i], A[N-i-1]);
}
```

### [Live demo](http://ideone.com/xPzOEw)

---

Of course, you can avoid *all* of this by simply asking the C++ standard library to do the work for you:

```
std::reverse(std::begin(A), std::end(A));
```

<sup>(thanks to @dasblinkenlight for [this last suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20522630/560648))</sup>

Comment: Thanks guys! Lightning helped me figure it out.

Comment: @user3091585: Reward me with a green tick if you feel me worthy!

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem with the logic of your code: once you do this

```
A[I] = A[N-I-1];
```

in the first iteration, the `1` is gone for good. Your array now looks like this:

```
5 2 3 4 5
```

and there is no way to put the `1` back where it was. The array should have looked like this

```
5 2 3 4 1
```

which means that you needed to swap the two elements.

A proper way to do what you are trying to do is to loop up to the middle of the array, and use the swap instead of the assignment (either through a function `std::swap` or by writing a swap yourself).

The fix that keeps most of your code is as follows

```
for (int I = 0; I < 2 /*stop at the middle*/; I++) {
    std::swap(A[I], A[N-I-1]);
}
```

The fix that uses the standard C++ library to its full potential is

```
std::reverse(std::begin(A), std::end(A));
```